# Is there a way to pass a variable to the html form action attribute?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm a newbie at programming and require your assistance -

In my python/flask `routes.py` script, I have a couple of `app.routes`.  I would like to pass the name of the route to an html form action field, such that the values in the form are posted to the route of that name;

```
@app.route('/interfaceStats', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def interfaceStats():
    routeName='interfaceStats'
    hostname = request.form['hostname']
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    command = ['python', 'readOperData.py', hostname, username,password]
    print(command)
    subIntObject = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=False)
    intObjectInString = subIntObject.decode('ascii')
    interfaceObjInJsonify = jsonify(intObjectInString)
    interfaceObjInJson = json.loads(intObjectInString) 
    return render_template('interfaceStats.html', interfaceObjInJson=interfaceObjInJson, hostname=hostname)



<form id="submit-form" action={{routeName}}  method="POST">
    Hostname:
    <input type="text", name="hostname" required>
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username" required>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

Error:

> the requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> 192.168.254.1 - - [09/May/2019 15:49:56] "GET /method=%22POST%22?hostname=192.168.253.144&username=admin&password=password
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your action attribute.

```
<form id="submit-form" action="{{routeName}}"  method="POST">
```